# Java: I want use Regex to count phone numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am a newbie to Regex. I am building a messaging app with windowbuilder eclipse that handles user putting series of phone numbers  and I want to use Regex to accomplish the following:

1. Get input from user from TextArea and count the phone numbers
2. total digit for each phone number is 11 (no spaces in between them)
3. only single spaces or comma between each phone number are allowed

I'm still learning Regex haven't gotten used to it so I would appreciate it if someone could provide a solution to my challenges. Thanks

Comment: We won't do the work for you. You need to try yourself. When you get stuck, you can come here and ask about the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Try this: \b(\d{11})\b

Comment: @tintin check out my answer...

Answer (score 2):

In order to read in input from text files :

ASCII is a TEXT file so you would use [Readers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) for reading. Java also supports reading from a binary file using [InputStreams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). If the files being read are huge then you would want to use a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) on top of a [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) to improve read performance.

Go through [this article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42) on how to use a Reader

**In Java 7**

[new String(Files.readAllBytes(...))](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) or [Files.readAllLines(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

**In Java 8**

[Files.lines(..).forEach(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)

myString.split("\\s+"); to split a String into an Array of substrings using all whitespace characters (' ', '\t', '\n', etc.) as delimiters.

Then iterate through the array and run a function to match the regex.

All you need is this function and you can call it repeatedly to get a `boolean` return on whether the number is valid or not.

```
private static boolean validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNo) 
{
    //validate phone numbers of format "1234567890"
    if (phoneNo.matches("\\d{11}")) return true;
}
```

The Regex can be modified by changing the number in brackets, `\d` means digits and `{11}` means 11 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to get the numbers and if you want a count you can just increment a counter in your `while loop`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String test = "12345678911,12345678922 12345678933";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{11}(?=\\b)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        String s = matcher.group(0);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
12345678911
12345678922
12345678933
```